# Hydrochloric acid from diaphragm electrolysis

Tags: electrolysis, salt, halogens

I have a diaphragm electrolysis cell, which is made up of an outer container containing the cathode and a small terra cotta pot containing the anode. If sodium chloride solution is placed in the outer container, distilled water is placed in the pot, and current is run through the solution, will hydrochloric acid form at the anode or will hypochlorous acid form? I know that chlorine reacts with hydroxide ion, but would there be a significant amount of hydroxide at the anode if it is separated by a diaphragm?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Putting pure water in the path of electric current is generally very bad idea.

Comment: I am only using 6v. Also, ions quickly travel across the diaphragm, so it doesn't stay pure water.